# How to retrieve the text in html CDATA section?

Tags: javascript, html, cdata

I have the following `script` element section in HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-markdown"><![CDATA[
# hello, This is Markdown Script Demo]]></script>
```

When i'm trying to retrieve the inner content via `scripttag.innerHTML`, it returns the text with `![CDATA[`...`]]>`parts

Is there more efficient way to retrieve the inner part of CDATA section at once instead of applying regexp to remove it from received `innerHTML` data?

Comment: CDATA sections are meaningless in HTML. The real question is what they are doing in an HTML document in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to retreive only whats inside the CDATA as its not a tag but plain text, when you get the innerHTML of the tag you will get everything as a string, so regexp is the only way I see you could get whats inside.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, but this might help somebody.

You can probably use textContent.

Example from parsing a rss feed node which looks like this:

```
<title><![CDATA[This contains the title]]></title>
```

Javascript:

```
const desc = el.querySelector('title').textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

CDATA is an XML concept. It is a way of specifying a section of text inside which things that look like mark-up or special XML characters are treated as plain text. It is essentially equivalent to escaping `<` to `&lt;` etc. everywhere within the CDATA section.

If the document has an HTML doctype, then the CDATA receives no special processing and is just more characters. If the document had an XHTML doctype, then you would be able to retrieve the CDATA section as is, with no further ado.